# What is the equivalent in F# of the C# default keyword?

Tags: c#, f#, default, keyword, c#-to-f#

I'm looking for the equivalent of C# `default` keyword, e.g:

```
public T GetNext()
{
    T temp = default(T);
            ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I found this in a blog: "[What does this C# code look like in F#? (part one: expressions and statements)](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry)"

> C# has an operator called "default"
>   that returns the zero-initialization
>   value of a given type:
>
> ```
> default(int)
> ```
>
> It has limited utility; most commonly you may use
>   default(T) in a generic.  F# has a
>   similar construct as a library
>   function:
>
> ```
> Unchecked.defaultof<int>
> ```

Answer (score 39):

Technically speaking the F# function `Unchecked.defaultof<'a>` is an equivalent to the `default` operator in C#. However, I think it is worth noting that `defaultof` is considered as an *unsafe* thing in F# and should be used only when it is really necessary (just like using `null`, which is also discouraged in F#).

In most situations, you can avoid the need for `defaultof` by using the `option<'a>` type. It allows you to represent the fact that a value is not available yet.

However, here is a brief example to demonstrate the idea. The following C# code:

```cs
    T temp = default(T);
    // Code that may call: temp = foo()
    if (temp == default(T)) temp = bar(arg)
    return temp;
```

Would be probably written like this in F# (using imperative features):

```ml
    let temp = ref None
    // Code that may call: temp := Some(foo())
    match !temp with 
    | None -> bar(arg)
    | Some(temp) -> temp
```

Of course this depends on your specific scenario and in some cases `defaultof` is the only thing you can do. However, I just wanted to point out that `defaultof` is used less frequently in F#.

Comment: In your C# example, you use an assignment operator instead of an equality operator inside the if statement. Is that deliberate?

Comment: I should say it doesn't work for me, let t = ref None
                                        t := Some(context.Items.FirstOrDefault(fun ii -> ii.Name = i.Name))
                                        match !t with                                            
                                        | Some it -> 
                                            - finished here even it is null
                                        | None -> ignore

Comment: @MartinBodocky your code will always return `Some(_)`. It either returns `Some(value)` or `Some(defaultof<>)` both will match the `Some _` case in your match expression. you could use `context.Items |> Seq.tryFind(fun II -> ii.Name = i.Name)` then the match expression would work as you expect